# Get html code as rendered

Tags: javascript, php, curl

This is my first post. I am not an expert and i am trying to get source html code but rendered... as we use the option "ispect element" from our browsers.

I tried the code bellow but it returns the source code (no rendered):

```
<?php

require_once ('url_to_absolute/simple_html_dom.php');

$masterurl = "http://www.myexamplesite.com/?p=154";

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($masterurl); 
$items = $html->find('article',0)->outertext;
echo $items;

?>
```

If the source url has youtube iframe my code returns it as an iframe again and not as rendered..

Is there any way to accomplish this with php?

Thanks to all of you

Comment: Inside <? Php ?> ??????

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP code is not being executed (I can see it on source code of page)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-i-can-see-it-on-source-code-of-page)

Comment: For example your site is example.com .. you want get the whole source code ? using a script ?

Comment: It's not a duplicate post!

Comment: <iframe src="http://www.myexamplesite.com/?p=154"> like this